# Visual Studio Code not picking up gulp tasks "Watching build tasks has finished"

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I have my gulp tasks:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
gulp.src('dev/sass/files/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./production/css/'))
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('default',function() {
gulp.watch('dev/sass/files/*.scss',['styles']);
});
```

which work when run from the console.

I have my tasks.json:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "gulp",
"isShellCommand": true,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "default",
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "isWatching": true
    }
 ]
}
```

When I run the build task via F1 and the command palette I get:

"Watching build tasks has finished"

The tasks haven't run and my CSS file hasn't been updated.

I have tried/checked:

- gulpfile is called gulpfile and in the root of my project
- gulp works from the console.  Both tasks (default and styles) are listed via gulp --tasks -simple
- both tasks can be successfully run from the console
- I have reinstalled VSCode - just in case that made any difference.  It didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my `ComSpec` environment variable was set to (note the semicolon):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;
```

To check yours, run this from the command line:

```
node -p process.env
```

You can change yours by using control panel and searching for environment variables.